# A facebook link not opening on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, hyperlink

I want to open a facebook comment page link Like

http://www.facebook.com/comments.php?href=http://wombeta.jiffysoftware.com/ViewWOMPrint.aspx?WPID=310

but problem is this link doesnot open in iphone device or simulator but opens fine on desktop.When i try to open this link on simulator it opens the m.facebook site then shows error "Could not find the page" Please tell me a way to open this link in iphone

My code is simple:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com/comments.php?href=http://wombeta.jiffysoftware.com/ViewWOMPrint.aspx?WPID=317"];

    NSURLRequest *requestObject = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObject];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

response of any url from FB server (like many other servers) is based on the "user agent" whenever a web call is made, the device automatically attach user agent with request. In your case the "user agent" is being sent by devices is the one of mobile Safari - Native iphone Safari app so the server is returning with mobile site response with m.facebook......

you need to find a mobile site equivalent link for the same and I'm pretty sure that FB will have it in some way or the other.

Best of Luck!

Answer (score -1):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com/comments.php?href=http://wombeta.jiffysoftware.com/ViewWOMPrint.aspx?WPID=317"]];
```

it will open safari browser and redirect to required URL.

Comment: It does work because you are getting redirection to the mobile site.